# How to use Keydown event in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have used $watch to detect my text length. I want to do when length !=0 can type  + , but why length !=0  can type +

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" numbers-only ng-model="Number"/>
    <hr />
    <p>Text {{Number}}</p>
    <p>Length {{Number.length}}</p>
    <p>Watch Lengh {{Watchlength}}</p>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

[here is my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duketopmost/0zdwLcdx/4/)

Can anyone help ? 
Thanks

Comment: Your question not clearly understand. Can you provide lot more explanation about your question?

Comment: First of all thank you for your response !!

I want to be able to enter the number of 01 to 29
when length = 0 just can  enter 0 1 2  the other can not enter

When the first string is 012, while the second string can accept 0-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want this to allow numbers only?

You can use a regular expression in a single line on an ng change event if you want to allow for something complex and strange, this will intercept the field changing, not the keypress and will be a lot easier to allow/deny changes... or better yet an angular filter or built in text input filter with no need for any controller at all, no need to build a complex directive with regular JavaScript keydown events... Yikes! :) lots of work for such an easy thing. :) you probably need a hug.

Also keydown won't work on all tablets or phones. Use ngchange instead...

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Also angular has built in keypress events...

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress

Comment: First of all thank you for your response !!

I want to be able to enter the number of 01 to 29
when length = 0 just can  enter 0 1 2  the other can not enter

When the first string is 012, while the second string can accept 0-9

Comment: You're right -
AngularJS lot of work has been done very well.
I renounce the use of javaScript to operate DOM element,
Thank you for giving me direction ..

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a `event.preventDefault()` when the user does '+'. That means it won't result in a typed character in your text box, so it doesn't change your model.

If you leave out `event.preventDefault()`, do you get what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
element.on("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.which === 107 && this.value.length === 0) { //this.value.length instead of watchlength
    console.log("++");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on ngModel validators. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController